# Extract text from pattern

Tags: c#, regex

i have a sim 800 module . i read all message that stored in sim card . that return bellow response . i want separate phone number,time and text from response . but i don't know how

```
+CMGL: 1,"REC READ","number","","2019/10/11 17:09:44+14"
this is text

+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","989149161278","","2019/10/11 17:38:18+14"
this is text

+CMGL: 3,"REC READ","989149161278","","2019/10/11 17:55:03+14"
this is text

+CMGL: 4,"REC READ","989149161278","","2019/10/11 17:57:09+14"
this is text

+CMGL: 5,"REC READ","989149161278","","2019/10/11 18:14:22+14"
this is text

+CMGL: 13,"REC READ","989149161278","","2019/10/11 19:04:40+14"
this is text

+CMGL: 14,"REC READ","989149161278","","2019/10/11 19:07:12+14"
this is text

+CMGL: 15,"REC READ","989149161278","","2019/10/11 19:08:23+14"
this is text

+CMGL: 16,"REC READ","989149161278","","2019/10/11 19:21:17+14"
this is text

+CMGL: 17,"REC READ","989149161278","","2019/10/11 19:30:31+14"
this is text

+CMGL: 18,"REC READ","989149161278","","2019/10/11 20:15:49+14"
this is text

+CMGL: 19,"REC READ","989149161278","","2019/10/11 20:41:36+14"
this is text

+CMGL: 20,"REC READ","number","","2019/10/11 20:41:41+14"
this is text

OK
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 2):

This may be not the best way, but considering your response structure will always stay the same, consider:

```
\+CMGL:\s\d+\,\"REC\sREAD\",\"(?<phone>.+)\",\"(?:.+)?\",\"(?<time>.+)\"|^(?<message>.+)$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fUuLTv/1)

Essentially, capturing the entire string and extracting necessary information via groups. You can access individual groups via group names (see link right side).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into this to fix your problem. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_regular_expressions.htm

Alternatively you can also use the string split method to divide up the content between your commas. 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-split-method-in-c-sharp-with-examples/